# express percent as a percentage of the total volume rather than ranked volume

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

Given this query:

```
select      [Code],         
            [EffectiveDate],
            [Volume] = Sum(Volume),
            [VolumeRank] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EffectiveDate ORDER BY SUM(Volume) DESC),
            [VolumePercent] = PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EffectiveDate ORDER BY SUM(Volume) ASC)
from        CodeTable
where       EffectiveDate between @start and @end
group by    DerivativeType, MemberCode, EffectiveDate
```

Which produces these results

```
X   2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 15683.00    1   1
X   2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 10524.00    1   1
Y   2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 8318.00     2   0.99236641221374
Y   2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 8264.00     2   0.991935483870968
```

The volume percent is calculating the *ranked* percentage, which makes sense!
I want to use a similar function to return the **percentage volume of the total volume** partitioned over the date, rather than a ranked percentage.

I am not seeing the wood for the trees...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you want to use a window function to calculate the total volume.  I think the logic is:

```
select sum(volume) / sum(sum(volume)) over (partition by EffectiveDate)
```

If `volume` is an integer, you should convert it to a non-integer number.  Otherwise, the division will return an integer -- and be either 0 or 1.  I often do this by multiplying by `1.0`:

```
select sum(volume*1.0) / sum(sum(volume)) over (partition by EffectiveDate)
```

The construct `sum(sum(volume))` looks strange the first time you see it.  The inner `sum()` is for the `group by`.  The outer `sum()` is for the window function -- to get the total after the aggregation.